# Problems in handleSubmit in Form in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am creating a login system by ReactJS. I have a problem while creating the login page. The following is my code:

```
export default class Login extends Component {
    state={
        data:{
            email:'',
            pass:''
        },
        loading:false,
        error:{}
    }
    handleChange=(e,{name,value})=>{
        this.setState({data:{[name]:value}});
        // console.log(this.state.data);
    }
    handleSubmit=()=>{
        const error=this.validate(this.state.data);
        this.setState({error:error});
        (_.isEmpty(this.state.error))
        ?(
        console.log(this.state.data)
        )
        :(console.log('Cannot submit'));
    }
    validate=(data)=>{
        const err={};
        if (!validator.isEmail(data.email)) {
            err.email='Invalid email'
        }
        if (!data.pass) {
            err.pass='Your password is missing'
        }
        return err;
    }
    render() {
        const {error}=this.state;
        return (
            <div className='login-form'>
                <Grid textAlign='center' style={{height:'100%', marginTop:80}} verticalAlign='middle'>
                <Grid.Column style={{maxWidth:500}}>
                <Form>
                <Segment raised textAlign='left'>
                <Header as='h2' color='blue' textAlign='center'>Please fill in login form</Header>
                <Form.Input fluid icon='mail' iconPosition='left' type='email' placeholder='Email' name='email' id='email' value={this.state.data.email} onChange={this.handleChange} required/>
                {(error.email)?(<InlineError text={error.email}/>):('')}

                <Form.Input fluid icon='privacy' iconPosition='left' type='password' placeholder='Password' name='pass' id='pass' value={this.state.data.pass} onChange={this.handleChange} required/>
                {(error.pass)?(<InlineError text={error.pass}/>):('')}
                <br/>
                <Checkbox label='Remember me'/>
                <br/>
                <Button color='blue' fluid size='medium' type='submit' onClick={this.handleSubmit}>Login</Button>
                </Segment>
                </Form>
                <Message attached='bottom' warning floating>New to us? <Link to='/signup'><a>Signup</a></Link></Message>
                </Grid.Column>
                </Grid>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

In my case, I want the form to be submitted successfully by displaying the user data in the console only when the {this.state.error} is empty. However, when I clicked the login button the first time, which I left an error intentionally, the form was submitted successfully and data was displayed in the console. I clicked it again the error was then displayed. Why was not the error shown in the first place? Can you tell me what is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do event.preventDefault() in

```
handleSubmit=(event)=>{
        event.preventDefault()
        const error=this.validate(this.state.data);
        if(error) {
           this.setState({error:error});
           return;
        }
        (_.isEmpty(this.state.error))
        ?(
        console.log(this.state.data)
        )
        :(console.log('Cannot submit'));
    }
```

because your button type is submit and it will reload the page